# Is there a way Material UI Select componet trigger an event when options change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

In Material UI select component, i have a onChange prop which it triggers when i select a new option, but, in my form i have to update this options, i need to trigger an event when my select component changes its options.

This is my component:

```
const Dropdown = (props) => {
 const [Selected, setSelected] = useState("");
 const handleChange = (values) => {
  setSelected(values.target.value);
  props.onChange({ values, name: props.name });
 };
 let Items = [...props.items];
 Items = orderArrayOfObjects(Items, "name");
  return (
<FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
  <InputLabel color="secondary" id={`label-${props.name}-${props.label}`}>
    {props.label}
  </InputLabel>
  <SelectComponent
    value={Selected}
    onChange={handleChange}
    name={props.name}
    color="secondary"
    variant="outlined"
    labelId={`${props.name}-${props.label}`}
    id={`select-${props.name}-${props.label}`}
    label={props.label}
  >
    {Items.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem key={index} value={item.value}>
          {item.name}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    })}
  </SelectComponent>
</FormControl>
```

);
};

Answer (score 2):

I think you should declare const Items by useState. And update them by useEffect on change of props.items. Changing state couse rerender and that should work